# Delphi debugger - go to line when exception happens

Tags: delphi, debugging, exception, line, delphi-xe2

I got switched to other project at work and I noticed that Delphi XE2 debugger does not show the line that raised exception. When i got back at home i started to investigate. Then I found out that it can be disabled in **Tools -> Options -> Debugger** options and check **Integrated debugging**. Also I unchecked everything under **Language exceptions** in **Exception types to ignore** list. **Notify on Language Exceptions** left checked. **Project -> Options -> Compiling**, I have defaults there and **Overflow** and **Range cheking** enabled. I am running **Debug** build. I **Cleaned** it.

I have not noticed before, but now Delphi debugger doesn't give me the line when I call this code:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _List: TStringList;
begin
  _List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Caption := _List[0]; // 'List index out of bounds (0)' here
  finally
    FreeAndNil(_List);
  end;
end;
```

but this works (provided only to show that debugger does show the line for some things):

```
{$R+} // Range check is ON
procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _myArray: array [1 .. 5] of string;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 5 do
  begin
    _myArray[i] := 'Element ' + IntToStr(i); // Range check error here
    ShowMessage('myArray[' + IntToStr(i) + '] = ' + _myArray[i]);
  end;
end;
```

What is happening here? How to make the debugger to show as much as possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `use debug dcu's` in the project options (only works if you actually have those dcu's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me answer the question first.

> **How to make the compiler show as much as possible**

The compiler shows you that the error is in the call to the btnclick.
The trick is to put a breakpoint on the first line of the btnclick proc with <kbd>F5</kbd>.
Then rebuild (!) the application and run again.
The execution will stop that the breakpoint.
Step through the code using <kbd>F8</kbd> until the error shows up.
Put a breakpoint <kbd>F5</kbd> on the line that generated the error.
Abort and rerun the application.
When you get to the second breakpoint instead of pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>, press <kbd>F7</kbd> to step inside the routine that causes the error, keep on pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> until you see what exactly is causing the problem.

**Why is this happening?**
The compiler traces back the source of the exception by following the stack trace.
Because in your case the code that generated the exception does not have stack trace (because it is not debug code), the compiler cannot do this trick and instead follows the stack trace that is **does** have; it moves one level up in your code and flags the exception there.

**A look at this in detail**
You're comparing apples and oranges.

This code (Exhibit A):

```
Caption := _List[0]; // 'List index out of bounds (0)' here
```

Has absolutely nothing in common with this code (Exhibit B):

```
_myArray: array [1 .. 5] of string;
....
_myArray[0]:= 'Hallo';
```

Exhibit A uses the TStringList class's `items` property, which is defined more or less as follows *(I've simplified it a bit, but the fundamentals are correct)*:

```
type
  TStringList = class(TStrings)
  strict private
    FList: array of string;
  ....
  private
    procedure Put(index: integer; const value: string);
    function Get(index: integer): string;
  published
    property Items[index: integer]: string read Get write Put; default;
    //   ------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^
    ....
  end;
```

Notice the `default` keyword at the end of the `Items` property.

What this all means is that when you call `_List[0]`, you are really calling `_List.Items[0]`, which gets translated into `Caption:= _List.Getitems(0)`, because of the read modifier on the property.
The `default` keyword allows you to omit the `.Items`.

The `Get` code looks like this:

```
function TStringList.Get(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  if Cardinal(Index) >= Cardinal(FCount) then
    Error(@SListIndexError, Index);  <<-Here is the line that generates the error*
  Result := FList[Index].FString;
end;
```

*<sub>Actually the error is generated inside the `Error` routine</sub>

Unless you have the RTL/VCL source code **and** you're running with debug DCU's you will not get a break on the exact trigger of the exception (which is inside the system.classes) unit.
Note that this error does not depend on range checking, it will always fire.
Because Delphi does not have debug info for the exact line where the error is generated, it does the next best thing and tries to make a guess.

**Short version**
The stringlist is a complex abstraction pretending to be an array.
Lots of code gets called, making the pinpointing of the error difficult for the compiler.

In Exhibit B:

```
_myArray: array [1 .. 5] of string;
....
i:= 0;   
_myArray[i]:= 'Hallo';
```

Either a range check error or an access violation is generated.
Both of these errors occur on the exact line, allowing the compiler to stop at the correct spot.

**Short version**
The **plain** array is a basic building block with no hidden calls to code elsewhere, making pinpointing errors very easy for the compiler.

**Understanding properties**
class and record properties (and now class operators) look like simple assignments/operations to/with variables, but are in fact calls to (possibly complex) subroutines.

Comment: I know that both codes I provided haves nothing in common. I provided it only to show that debugger gives me no line of code only for 'List index out of bounds' exception. Yes, breakpoints helps, but things gets complicated when there are gazillion lines of code. I only wonder why sometimes debugger gives me the line thats causing problems and sometimes not.

Comment: That's what I told you, the exception is not generated in your code, so the debugger does not stop in your code.